# Proving $1 + 2 + 2^2+2^3 + 2^4 + \dots+ 2^{n-1}= 2^n -1$ using mathematical induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I'm taking Pre-Calc, and if anyone could go through step-by-step on this problem I’d appreciate it greatly. ;)

> Use mathematical induction to prove the formula for every positive integer n.
>
> $$1 + 2 + 2^2+2^3 + 2^4 + \dots+ 2^{n-1}= 2^n -1$$

Comment: This question has, undoubtedly, been asked many times on this site.

Comment: Really? I’m new to the site

Comment: Can you see why the case $n=1$ works? Can you see why if $n=k$ works so does $n=k+1$?

Comment: How you simplify 2^(k) -1 + 2^k